# wordpress rewrite query string to remove reserved words

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site that is getting redirects from a provider that contain "name=blahblah" in the url query string.  Name is a reserved word so these end up not resolving and we get "page not found".

I have tried adding rewrite rules to strip the query strings out, but nothing seems to work:

```
    add_rewrite_rule('^/?mypage=(.*)&', 'index.php?mypage=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Ideally I would like to change their name query string into something I can capture and use, but I would settle to just being able to load the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up 'solving' this by adding `unset($_GET[name])` to my functions.php to execute before wordpress does anything.  I'm pretty sure this is a bad solution, but it works.

Comment: Did you find any better solution? When unsetting the name my product single page doesn't load (woocommerce).